403 when downloading a file via PHP but not from browser
I have a 403 error when downloading a JSON file via PHP from a URL. I can open the file from the browser without problems (no errors in the dev tools).
This is the script (minus the actual URL), which I have verified as working with other sites:
$ch = curl_init($url);
$dir = '../sources/';
$file_name = basename($url);
$save_file_loc = $dir . $file_name;
$fp = fopen($save_file_loc, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:/Program \Files/php/cacert.pem');
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch)."\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

The certificate comes from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html. This is the info I get:
    [url] => the/url/path/to/json/file
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 403
    [header_size] => 183
    [request_size] => 83
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.516273
    [namelookup_time] => 0.065622
    [connect_time] => 0.091481
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.483309
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 418
    [speed_download] => 809
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 418
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.516216
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] =>
    [primary_ip] => (the.url.primary.ip.address)
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => (my.local.ip)
    [local_port] => 65046
    [http_version] => 3
    [protocol] => 2
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => HTTPS
    [appconnect_time_us] => 483121
    [connect_time_us] => 91481
    [namelookup_time_us] => 65622
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 483309
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 516216
    [total_time_us] => 516273
    [effective_method] => GET

Of course I tried setting a user agent as well, but no chance.
What am I missing?

You need to compare the differences between all data in the curl request and the browser request, such as UA, referer, body, etc.

You missed a user agent string. Supply it in your CURL call. See this

'C:/Program \Files/php/cacert.pem' has an extra backslash.

The site operators are clearly defending against bots and scrapers. Even if you match a browser request exactly you may find you still get 403. Check the site's terms of service: it probably forbids what you're trying to do. Does the site have an API? If so, you should use that.

In replying to some of the comments ...
@Raptor - tried with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');, no difference
@Olivier - moved the file to C:/php/cacert.pem and changed path, no change
@TangentiallyPerpendicular - I believe you might be right, re. the site blocking scrapers. The site has an API for registered users but in that case it's odd the URL is accessible

Is the resource behing a login gate? 403 suggests that you need to be authenticated...

@HonkderHase - there's no login date

403 Forbidden.
The server is question is probably blocking you from downloading the file. I would reach out to them to find out firstly if you are allowed to be fetching the file using a script, and additionally how you might be able to do that.
If they have particularly weak checks then this might work, but if not your in for a whole lot of pain trying to trick their server into thinking you are legitimate:
$url = ''; //url to scrape
$referrer = ''; //sensible url such as the homepage of their site
$dir = '../sources/'; //directory to store file

$curl = curl_init();

$file_name = basename($url);
$save_file_loc = $dir . $file_name;
$fp = fopen($save_file_loc, 'wb');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0');

$header = array();
$header[] = "Accept: */*";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_errno($curl)."\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
curl_close($curl);
fclose($fp);

